# React - api data not visible in the ui?

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, fetch-api, use-effect

So I am trying to display the location and the weather for the next couple of days but I am just having a hard time displaying the data in the ui - I am pretty new to react, would really appreciate any inputs

Here is the code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new?file=/src/App.js)

```
import "./styles.css";

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";


// goal : to display the weather shown every 3 hours for the next days 

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);  
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);


  const api = "https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/2.0/complete?lat=-16.516667&lon=-68.166667&altitude=4150";
  useEffect(() => {
   if (!api) return;
    setLoading(true);
    fetch(api)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(setData)
      .then(() => setLoading(false))
      .catch(setError);
  }, []);

  
console.log(data)

  if (loading) return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
  if (error) return <pre>{JSON.stringify(error, null, 2)}</pre>;
  if (!data) return null;

  if (data) {
    return ( 
      <div className="Layout">

<p> Cordinates here </p>

<p>{data.geometry.coordinates[0]}</p>

{data.geometry.coordinates.map((i) => (
  <ul  key={i.geometry}>
  <li>{i.coordinates}</li>
</ul>
))}
<p> Timeseries here </p>
  
{data.properties.timeseries.map((i) => (
  <ul key={i.timeseries}>
  <li>{i.timeseries}</li>
</ul>
))}

    </div>
    );
  }
  return <div> Could not get the data</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some issue in how you handled the map method. Edit it as follows

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";


// goal : to display the weather shown every 3 hours for the next days 

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);  
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);


  const api = "https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/2.0/complete?lat=-16.516667&lon=-68.166667&altitude=4150";
  useEffect(() => {
   if (!api) return;
    setLoading(true);
    fetch(api)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(setData)
      .then(() => setLoading(false))
      .catch(setError);
  }, []);

  
console.log(data)

  if (loading) return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
  if (error) return <pre>{JSON.stringify(error, null, 2)}</pre>;
  if (!data) return null;

  if (data) {
    return ( 
      <div className="Layout">

<p> Cordinates here </p>

<p>{data.geometry.coordinates[0]}</p>

{data.geometry.coordinates.map((i) => (
  <ul  key={i.geometry}>
  <li>{i}</li>
</ul>
))}
<p> Timeseries here </p>
  
{data.properties.timeseries.map((j) => (
  <ul key={j.timeseries}>
  <li>{j.time}</li>
</ul>
))}

    </div>
    );
  }
  return <div> Could not get the data</div>;
}
```

Codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-pond-hmd4p)